# List contain only one string in integer list

Tags: python

EDIT1:
i have problem about converting a string in a list. I collect only numbers from a file. Then convert them into integer. Using,

```
For line in range (0,len(file_name):
   file_name[line] = int (file_name[line])
```

It worked, every number converted string to integer but only one number remain string. [2,4,'3']. Now, how can i convert that string into integer.
Thanks

Comment: Please show the original content of `file_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a list comprehension instead of a manual for loop.

```
file_name = [int(i) for i in file_name]
```

Comment: Why not `file_name = list(map(int, file_name))`, then?